# Lip pain when playing flute: how to overcome?

Tags: technique, flute, health, embouchure

I have noticed that when I play higher octave notes on the flute my lips start to hurt. This has happened before but I dealt with it just by ignoring the pain.

I would like to know whether there is anything I could adjust to make playing less painful? Also, could this indicate my way of blowing the flute is wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no doubt that you don't have sufficient breath control here.  I have experienced similar problems (clarinet, sax) as have friends on brass instruments while learning and improving our breathing & diaphragm control.
When your lips or jaw get fatigued, **stop and rest**.

But above all,  my oft-used directive on Music.SE applies: Get Thee To A Teacher.

Answer (score 5):

If it hurts, it's wrong.  Many players can play higher octaves all evening without pain.  But to diagnose what exactly is wrong, someone would need to see and hear you playing.  If you're lucky, posting a video would work.  But more likely, you need a teacher or a more experienced colleague in the room with you to ask you to try different things and observe the result.

Comment: this, unfortunately, is the right answer.

Comment: Stack Exchange started with computer programming questions.  Those are much more easily posed and answered than these.  ("Learn Flute By Mail" is a classic punch line...)

Comment: I'd just add, it depends on how far along the player is, and what counts as "pain". I remember in my first year a lot of aching lip muscles.  Intense pain is a sign of something wrong, but there is a certain amount of sufferning involved in getting a good flute embouchure.

Comment: @ScottWallace  Dang!  I thought you only had to suffer if you want to play the Blues :-)

Comment: @CamilleGoudeseune Thank you for your input. I am not sure what your remark about learning the flute by mail is about though, as I don't intend to rely on the internet alone. And if there is an SE for music, why not use it?

Comment: "Learn flute by mail" is just an old-fashioned way of saying that some things are learned best when the teacher's in the same room as you.